# Bash time converter

Tags: bash, time

I have a question, How can I convert time from 12h AM/PM format to 24h?
For example, I have input from stdin, some text like this:

```
The event starts at 03:25PM and is expected to end at 06:17PM.
Registration will be opened from 09:00AM until 06:00 PM.
The event starts at 15:25 and is expected to end at 18:17.
Registration will be opened from 09:00 until 06:00 PM.
```

How can I read all hh:mmPM and hh:mmAM and convert it? But I don’t want to use awk or smth like it. How can I do it with only bash loops, if/else, echo, sed etc? Thanks!

Comment: No awk, but sed is OK? Can you tell us what makes an external tool acceptable? What about cut, perl, ed, tac, rev, head, tail, sort, paste, ...

Comment: @choroba, i know that with some tools we can do it easier, but i want to find a little bit hard way:D i guess, acceptable tool is only sed(to make a work with text easier).

Comment: How modern a version of bash?

Comment: You say "I don't want to use [something like] `awk`" and at the same time "How can I do it with [...] `sed`?"  `sed` is _very_ similar to `awk`, so your request contradicts itself.  It also doesn't help that your times in the input file are very irregular- some have a space between the minutes and AM/PM indicator; some do not.  Some omit the AM/PM entirely.  If your input is inconsistent is is nigh-impossible to make something to automagically generate desired output for it.

Comment: @icarus , 5.1.8(1)-release

Comment: @DopeGhoti , sorry, my problem. I want to use sed, but don't use awk. What about a format of time. I want to have in input format of time only like in my example, hh:mmAM and hh:mmPM .

Comment: In your example, you also have `hh:mm PM` with a space.

Comment: @choroba , Can I count it in my program with this 2 formats with using sed?

Comment: My answer handles both the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the sed script that replaces the numbers:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
for pm in {0..11} ; do
    (( h = pm + 12 ))
    pm=$(printf %02d $pm)
    echo "s/$pm\(:[0-9][0-9]\) \?PM/$h\1/g"
done | sed -e 's/ \?AM//g' -f- input.txt
```

The loop produces the following script:

```
s/00\(:[0-9][0-9]\) \?PM/12\1/g
s/01\(:[0-9][0-9]\) \?PM/13\1/g
s/02\(:[0-9][0-9]\) \?PM/14\1/g
s/03\(:[0-9][0-9]\) \?PM/15\1/g
s/04\(:[0-9][0-9]\) \?PM/16\1/g
s/05\(:[0-9][0-9]\) \?PM/17\1/g
s/06\(:[0-9][0-9]\) \?PM/18\1/g
s/07\(:[0-9][0-9]\) \?PM/19\1/g
s/08\(:[0-9][0-9]\) \?PM/20\1/g
s/09\(:[0-9][0-9]\) \?PM/21\1/g
s/10\(:[0-9][0-9]\) \?PM/22\1/g
s/11\(:[0-9][0-9]\) \?PM/23\1/g
```

The extra expression removes `AM` while keeping the time untouched.